# How to extract a portion of Varbinary and store that in a variable in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, byte

I'm trying to utilizing the Microsoft Graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http#step-2-use-the-upload-session-to-upload-a-range-of-bytes-of-the-file) to create an upload session and send an attachment. However when I send the base64 version of bytes of the attachment (pdf) my file is corrupted and isn't compiling correctly. We also have the raw bytes - varbinary (not encoded). How can I pull a portion of the bytes from and query that in SSIS? Essentially when I did it using the base64 encoded bytes I would pull out the portion of the bytes using the substring. When I try using the varbinary and querying that in SSIS, I get no data when I store it in a byte variable. I didn't have any issues using the base64 version since it was a NVARCHAR, but it seems that isn't what the API needs.

To clarify, I am able to use the substring function on the varbinary column, however when that data gets sent back to SSIS, it is unable to store it, even in an object.

What is being sent per iteration using base64:

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1386170
Content-Range: bytes 2097152-3483321/3483322

{
JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCj....
}

What should be sent using varbinary:

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1386170
Content-Range: bytes 2097152-3483321/3483322

{
0x4A0056004200....
}

Comment: Could you explain or show what you've done in SSIS so far?  Then we can see what's getting converted where.

Comment: When you say you used a "byte" variable, do you mean it had an SSIS type of `DT_BYTES`, or `DT_IMAGE`? The `DT_BYTES` type has a maximum length of 8000 bytes. `DT_IMAGE` can be up to 2 gigabytes.

Comment: @allmhuran I am using SSIS variables, so this wouldn't be a data types similar in Data Transformations / Data Sources etc. I am running an execute sql task, saving the result to an object variable, then assigning each row's attribute to a variable in my for loop container for each iteration/ API request

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz  Create a Draft Email: No problems here, I make the API call, get the new message ID for the draft. Create the upload session: Utilizing the new message ID created in the draft process. Get the response of the upload session and save the URL used for the iterations of sending the bytes. Lastly I have an execute SQL task, this is pulling the metrics needed for the API calls. The content range and bytes, I then utilize the object which stores this data and make calls using a for loop container.

Comment: What is the data type of the SQL column?  Are you doing any conversions or using any functions on that or is it being query straight out?  What is the data type of the variable that the blob column is being written to?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I was originally using the NVARCHAR column of the base64 bytes. This wasn't working. What I am trying now is converting the varbinary to NVARCHAR, but without any transformation. i.e. I'm storing 0x4A0056004200 (varbinary) as 0x4A0056004200, but in a NVARCHAR. The variable used to store this version right now is string (ssis variable data type), I have no issues when I store the binary NVARCHAR version in variable and loop through.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Data is coming through correctly but I think what also might be causing my issue is the content length being sent in? What I'm doing right now is taking the varbinary max, storing that in an nvarchar max, and using the LEN function to get the length of that. However I think getting the length of the previous varbinary / nvarchar max now is being double/tripled. The original file was 5MB. When a LEN is ran on the base64 is it around 7, which is right. It increases a bit after encoding. But when I do the LEN on the varbinary max that is transformed it was bigger, like 28MB

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz This is my size/content lengths are right now:

Original Size: 5265459 (this is original meta data given from the API)
SQL Base64(nvarchar) Length: 7009904
SQL Bytes(varbinary max) Length: 14019808
SQL Bytes(varbinary max) transformed to NVARCHAR (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), contentBytes, 1)) Length: 28039618

Comment: You are converting the column in sql from varbinary to nvarchar(max)?

Comment: I would try going from varbinary in sql to the `byte` type in ssis.

Comment: I see, so you're running execute sql task, putting the result set into an object in SSIS, then iterating over the contents to pull out a blob, which you tried to assign to a byte variable (and also an object variable) which didn't work? And in the source database you currently have an `nvarchar` column, but you are loading that column with a "stringified" representation of a `varbinary`? Ie, for a `varbinary` value of 0x01, you would be storing a `varchar` value of "0x01"? And now you are storing the result a `string` in SSIS rather than the (previously unsuccessful) `byte` or `object`?

Comment: Aside... the base64 symbols are all, by definition, ASCII characters so using `nvarchar(anything)` to store them is wasteful and unnecessary.

Comment: Seems like your base64 encoding process is broken. It should be transforming every 3 input bytes to 4 ASCII characters, so an input of 5,265,459 bytes should be transformed to exactly 7,020,612 characters.

Comment: Aside... if you're putting base64 encoded data on the wire instead of a binary blob then it seems you're missing a `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` header to notify the receiving party that they need to decode it.